# firebase onUpdate function is not triggering

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I tries to trigger .onUpdate function when my count variable in data structure changes. Though the count variable changes still functions is not triggered.
My count variable is below main realtime database.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    
// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.cleanStorage=functions.database
    .ref('/count')
    .onUpdate((change,context)=>{
    
    
    if(change.before.count===change.after.count){
    return null;
     }
    
     const newCount=change.after.count-7;
    
    
    return change.after.ref.update({count:newCount});
});
```

[image: data structure]

Comment: Did you try `console.log` the `change.before.count` to see what it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Prashin Jeevaganth in his comment, you should debug your code. You will see that `change.before.count` and `change.after.count` are `undefined`, which explains why nothing happens.

Have a look at the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events?authuser=0#reading_the_previous_value): you need to use the `val()` method as follows:

```
exports.cleanStorage = functions.database
    .ref('/count')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {

        if (change.before.val() === change.after.val()) {
            return null;
        }

        const newCount = change.after.val() - 7;

        return change.after.ref.parent.update({ count: newCount });
    });
```

**IMPORTANT:** Note that with this code you will probably enter in an infinite loop, because you will update the node, which will trigger the Cloud Function. You may update another node, for example:

```
return change.after.ref.child('newCount').update({ count: newCount });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) `before` and `after` both return `DataSnapshot`. This means that if you want the get value you have to use 'val()'.

Due to above `if` statement from the code sample will always be `undefined===undefined` which resolves as `true` so the function will always return `null`.

I do not have playground to test it but I would try change `if` statement to:

if( change.before.val() == change.after.val() )

Probably there are more ways to do it... I hope it will help!